# Вывод значений из БД

Tags: php, mysql

Допустим есть таблица `items` состоящая из:

`id | name | desc |`

и она заполнена различными данными

Как мне вывести все данные по очереди (место в соответствии с id) в таблицу? (при этом id не выводить на страницу)

Таблица

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td>Desc 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item 2</td>
    <td>Desc 2</td>
</table>
```

Таблица не ограничена, выводить в порядке с id. То есть если id = 1, то элемент на 1 месте.

Comment: Т.е. если, например, первый ряд таблицы иметт id 10 - должно быть 9 пустых ячеек в таблице перед его выводом? или просто все по порядку?

Comment: просто вывод по порядку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

например можно так:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli( 'адрес БД', 'пользователь', 'пароль', 'база данных' );
$query = 'SELECT name, desc FROM items';
$result = $mysqli -> query( $query );
while( $row = $result -> fetch_row())
    echo
    '<tr>' .
        '<td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $row['desc'] . '</td>' .
    '</tr>';
```

Comment: fatal error на строчке 4

Comment: Я так понимаю у ТСа просто mysql =)

Comment: Выше код приводит к ошибкам при большой базе
jquery.min.js:4 POST wordpress.../assets/myajax.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0):

```
function fetch($res){
     while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){$data[] = $row;}
     return $data;
}
// Connect to database
$itemsData = fetch(mysql_query('SELECT * FROM items'));
include_once 'tpl.html';
```

В tpl.html:

```
<table>
    <?foreach($itemsData as $item):?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$item['name']?></td>
            <td><?=$item['desc']?></td>
        </tr>
    <?endforeach?>
<table>
```

Comment: пустое окно выводит

Comment: tpl.html подключили?
Убедитесь в том что шаблон подключается, стесняюсь спросить - в БД вообще есть данные?

Comment: подключил, данные есть